# Angular 2 app: route content is blank on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, angular, angular-ui-router

I am having a weird issue, with my routes in my angular app. This issue only happens on iOS

Whenever i click on one of my route links in my navigation menu, the page navigates to that route, but the page is blank. It seems like the actual content isn't in the `router-outlet`. However, when I inspect the elements using Safari Remote inspection. I can see, that all the elements are there, and there is allocated space on the screen for them as well. If I click on the items on the screen (which are still not visible), their click events are fired.

Here is a screenshot of the inspected element and the blank page (notice that the screen is blue, because I am hovering over the element (in safari dev tool) in the component which is selected with the router.

​
[image: safari]

[image: dev tools]

However, if I refresh the page, or type the URL directly into the address bar, then the component is shown as it is supposed to. (this particular example is www.appollodev.com/#/events​ )
and the page is on www.appollodev.com​ (built using "ng build --prod --aot")
You can use the links to try it out for yourself if you have an iOS device. Just go to the root page and then use the burger-menu in the top right corner to access the pages (route links on div elements). None of the routes work, my example is with the EVENTS link.
**Additional information:**
Try yourself here: www.appollodev.com

Versions of stuff:

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1
node: 6.10.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1
@angular/common: 2.4.9
@angular/compiler: 2.4.9
@angular/core: 2.4.9
@angular/forms: 2.4.9
@angular/http: 2.4.9
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.9
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.9
@angular/router: 3.4.9
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.9

npm version: 4.4.4

iOS version: 10.0.1 (14A403)
```

Doesn't work on:

```
iOS -> Chrome
iOS -> Safari
iOS -> Firefox
```

Works on:

```
Windows 8.1 -> Chrome, Safari, Firefox
OS X -> Chrome, Safari, Firefox​
Android -> Chrome, Safari, Firefox​
```

I am at a loss after hours of searching online for this bug, hopefully someone can help.​
The bug appears both with and without the HashLocationStrategy

Sorry about the urls not being links, Stackoverflow only allows me to have 1 link :(

Comment: any progress with the issue? I am stuck somewhere similar to yours.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue  for iPad  Chrome, Safari, Firefox

Answer (score 2):

Have the same issue, with my ipad air 2 and ios 10. I tried all browsers, from safari to dolphin. Just certain router-outlet not rendering at all. Hope somebody find how to solve this problem, because I can't debug ios from my linux laptop. Also, on android all works like a charm.